# Spacing of lines evenly space on a circle when viewed from the side

Tags: calculus, geometry

Hi there I am an architect trying to create a script in python or grasshopper to offset or space lines with diminishing distance between spaces to represent a curved piece of cabinetry [Cabinet Isometric View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5TOr.jpg), [Cabinet Side Views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYybe.jpg).

I want to be able to do this in 2-dimensional drawing space, but essentially what I am looking for is if you were to space lines on a circle in 3D space [Evenly Space lines on circle - Isometric View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drV7X.jpg) then view 3D drawing from the side [Evenly Space lines on circle - Side View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qgk5L.jpg), what equation or formula would govern the distance between those lines if measured from a flat side plane.

Could somebody please help me or at least point me in the right direction for what I am looking for to help me come up with an equation or python script to define the spacing of these lines. My current method of just eyeballing it is not ideal.

Ideally I want the equation/script to be parametric and allow me to change (1) the distance which I need to cover with lines, and (2) the number of lines in that distance. Which together would effectively control the density of lines.

Answer (score 1):

The formula is:
$$f(r,n,i) = r\cdot \sin(90\cdot\frac{i-1}{n-1})$$

Here $r$ is the distance covered, $n$ is the number of lines you want (must be at least $2$, one to mark the start and one to mark the end). Then put in $i$ as any value from $1$ to $n$ and the formula gives the distance of the $i$-th line. This distance is a number between $0$ (for $i=1$) and $r$ (for $i=n$) with the lines far apart near $0$ and close together near $r$.